# 画像アップロード → 指定サイズになるまで並べる → 1枚画像として保存

Tags: javascript, php, 画像, imagemagick

**下記を実装したいのですが、どうすれば良いでしょうか？**
・画像アップロード
・指定サイズになるまで(XY方向に)並べる
・1枚画像として保存

**質問**
・画像アップロード後、画像自体を拡大したり、画像自体をトリミングするImageMagickサンプルはネットで見かけた気がするのですが、「指定サイズになるまで並べる」というのをどうしたら良いか分かりません
・CSSで並べて表示後、その要素のキャプチャを取得？
・そんなことをしなくても、ImageMagickでどうにか出来るでしょうか？

**その他**
・継ぎ目はシームレスではなく、ただ単に繰り返し並べるだけ
・ImageMagickでなくても良いです

Comment: 並べるというのはつまり指定サイズの画像に素材画像を繰り返しコピーするわけですから、Imagickなら[compositeImageで](http://php.net/manual/ja/imagick.examples-1.php#example-3632)、あとはGDなら[imagecopy](http://php.net/manual/ja/function.imagecopy.php)あたりで・・・ってそういう話でしょうか。

Comment: 画像サイズと指定サイズから縦横何枚必要か分かるでしょうからそれで[ImageMagickで結合](http://www.image-magick.com/compose/tile/)すればいいのでは？

Comment: リンクを確認してみたのですが、「compositeImage」よりも「montage」の方が目的に近い気がするので、結合後トリミングという流れで検討してみます

Answer (score 1):

GDで簡単に実装できそうですね。
下記サンプルは、はみ出た分はどうするのかわからないので、はみ出すようにしてます。
画像がPOSTされているかどうかのチェックは入れていないので、ご自身で入れてみてください。

```
<?php

// 指定する画像の高さ
$maxHeight = (int) $_POST['max_height'];

// 指定する画像の幅
$maxWidth = (int) $_POST['max_width'];

// アップロードされた画像
$image = $_FILES['image']['tmp_file'];

// /で分割
$mimeType = explode('/', $_FILES['image']['type']);

if ($mimeType[1] === 'jpeg' || $mimeType[1] === 'png' || $mimeType[1] === 'gif') {

    // アップロードされた画像をGDにする
    $functionName = 'imagecreatefrom' . $mimeType[1];
    $gdImage = $functionName($image);

    // 画像の高さ
    $imageHeight = imagesy($gdImage);

    // 画像の幅
    $imageWidth = imagesx($gdImage);

    // コピー対象用のGD
    $result = imagecreatetruecolor($maxWidth, $maxHeight);

    // 縦方向にコピーする回数 (はみ出さない場合はfloor)
    $copyY = ceil($maxHeight / $imageHeight);

    // 横方向にコピーする回数 (はみ出さない場合はfloor)
    $copyX = ceil($maxWidth / $imageWidth);

    // コピーしていく
    for ($y = 0; $y < $copyY; $y++) {
        for ($x = 0; $x < $copyX; $x++) {
            imagecopy($result , $gdImage, $x * $imageWidth, $y * $imageHeight, 0, 0, $imageWidth, $imageHeight);
        }
    }

    // 結果を出力する
    $outputFunctionName = 'image' . $mimeType[1];
    $outputFunctionName($result, './output.' . $mimeType[1]);

}
```